# Adding non-ssh user to git

Tags: git

I have a private git server with a few users who can access the git via ssh-keys. Is it possible to add a user that can authenticate with a password?

Why would I possibly want this?
We have a Microsoft Devops which does not allow adding external git repos via ssh keys, only via passwords.

[image]

Comment: What software do you run at the git server? Just `ssh` and `git` or something bigger? Well, anyway a user at the host can use `ssh` without keys — with a password.

Comment: Just ssh and git. I'm going to try your approach

Comment: The downside is that there is no way to cache ssh passwords. Even for https there are ways to cache password. But for ssh without keys the password has to be typed for every operation.

Comment: Well, I just found out the git url can't be ssh, and should be the http or https protocol.  I will have to find out how to host git on https and ssh.